# Список сокращений. Использование сокращений в тексте

Tags: аббревиатуры, оформление-текста, условные-сокращения

Если в начале документа имеется таблица основных сокращений, далее включённые в текст, где встречаются расшифровки из этого списка, необходимо ли при первом упоминании приводить аббревиатуру или достаточно таблицы сокращений?

Например, в таблице мы указали расшифровку "ПО — программное обеспечение".
Далее в первом разделе документа мы пишем: "...программное обеспечение (ПО) предназначено...". Нужно ли оставлять (ПО)? Или не нужно? И далее в тексте мы можем указывать и сокращенную "ПО" и полную форму "программное обеспечение".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю, что если весь список сокращений приведён отдельно, то расшифровки в тексте ни к чему. А использовать можно обе формы, потому как в начале указано, что ПО = программное обеспечение, и перед прочтением основного текста предполагается ознакомление со списком сокращений.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно при написании диссертации, ГОСТ Р 7.0.11-2011 "Система стандартов по информации, библиотечному и издательскому делу. Диссертация и автореферат":

> Наличие перечня не исключает расшифровку сокращения и условного
> обозначения при первом упоминании в тексте.

Однако, если документ делается по ЕСКД/ЕСПД, то ГОСТ 2.105-95 говорит:

> При необходимости применения условных обозначений, изображений или знаков, не установленных действующими стандартами, их следует пояснять в тексте или в перечне обозначений.

Не любят инженеры избыточные конструкции. Поэтому "в тексте ***или*** в перечне", но не одновременно. Перечень рекомендуется, если сокращений от пяти и больше.